# Rule/practice for the location of storing config files

Tags: ros, best-practices

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On Ubuntu Quantal with Groovy on my home dir, I see hidden dirs:

```
.gazebo
.ros  (might be used for storing logs only?) (*1)
.rviz
```

Also, there could be pkgs that store their config in arbitrary location. For example [rqt_gui](http://ros.org/wiki/rqt_gui) stores its setting in `~/.config/ros.org/rqt_gui.ini`, which I had a hard time in finding by file search (grep, find) and ended up looking into its code (this is not documented either).

Is there any good rule / practice to standardize the config/setting files' location ROS-wide?

---

*1...3/4/2013 turned out false. See [wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_HOME)

---

**Update** 3/11/2013 For `rqt_gui` specifically, it will keep using `~/.config` folder since it is/will be not fully ROS-dependent. See [discussion here](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt/issues/69).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53861/rule/practice-for-the-location-of-storing-config-files/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-01-31

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The normal ROS practice is to use some subdirectory of $ROS_HOME for storing data generated from ROS nodes.

If $ROS_HOME is not defined, use `~/.ros` as a default.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-03-04**:
I see also it's [documented here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_HOME).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Writing a few packages, I encountered the same problem: where do I save my data?

I used this [little trick from stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910377/get-home-directory-in-linux-c) to get the user home dir, and then save in my own subfolder, or in an aptly named folder under the .ros folder.

---

Originally posted by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) with karma: 859 on 2013-03-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1